# Pull data from Salesforce Chatter into a SharePoint list?

Tags: 2010, list, custom, query

We're looking to query data driven within [Salesforce Chatter](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/overview/) and pull relevant information into a SharePoint list. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,check this video [Sharepoint Salesforce.com Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNh8XZ6q6-c)

Or use the 3rd party App [Chatter for SharePoint](http://sharepointsnapple.com/chatter-for-sharepoint/) – the leading solution for integrating your SharePoint collaboration platform with SalesForce Chatter

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce has an connected app architecture where you can register an app which will give an access uri and key to the required resources.

you can now write a custom solution using the oath via the generated key and then get the access token.

now pull the chatter information and store them in to sharepoint via onject model or CSOM